# "Hardware acceleration" on Chromium-based programs is horrifically slow and unresponsive on Windows 11

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I am on Windows 11, and for some reason, using Chromium-based programs like Edge, Chrome, and Visual Studio Code are unusable in how slow and unresponsive they are. Edge is now back to normal when I disabled Hardware Acceleration in the Settings. I can't confirm this, but I believe these problems started around January. I have Intel UHD graphics 630 on Windows 11. When I search this up, I only get sketchy spam about Chrome just running slow in general, or unrelated problems. My drivers are updated.

Here is the "problems" list on edge://gpu :

```
Problems Detected
Accelerated video decode has been disabled, either via blocklist, about:flags or the command line.
Disabled Features: video_decode
Some drivers are unable to reset the D3D device in the GPU process sandbox
Applied Workarounds: exit_on_context_lost
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
On Intel GPUs MSAA performance is not acceptable for GPU rasterization: 527565
Applied Workarounds: msaa_is_slow
Disable KHR_blend_equation_advanced until cc shaders are updated: 661715
Applied Workarounds: disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced), disable(GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent)
Decode and Encode before generateMipmap for srgb format textures on Windows: 634519
Applied Workarounds: decode_encode_srgb_for_generatemipmap
Expose WebGL's disjoint_timer_query extensions on platforms with site isolation: 808744, 870491
Applied Workarounds: enable_webgl_timer_query_extensions
Disable DecodeSwapChain for Intel Gen9 and older devices: 1107403
Applied Workarounds: disable_decode_swap_chain
Intel GPUs fail to report BGRA8 overlay support: 1119491
Applied Workarounds: enable_bgra8_overlays_with_yuv_overlay_support
8x MSAA for WebGL contexts is slow on Win Intel: 1145793
Applied Workarounds: max_msaa_sample_count_4
Disable software overlays for Intel GPUs. All Skylake+ devices support hw overlays, older devices peform poorly.: 1192748
Applied Workarounds: disable_direct_composition_sw_video_overlays
Check YCbCr_Studio_G22_Left_P709 color space for NV12 overlay support on Intel: 1103852
Applied Workarounds: check_ycbcr_studio_g22_left_p709_for_nv12_support
Intel GPUs do not promote downscaled overlays: 1245835
Applied Workarounds: no_downscaled_overlay_promotion
AVC/AV1 hardware encoder MFT output bitrate incorrect upon framerate update on Intel GPUs.: 1295815
Applied Workarounds: disable_dynamic_video_encode_framerate_update
Patch LockFileEx for Intel and cancel all timeout I/O
Applied Workarounds: patch_lockfileex_on_intel_drivers
```

Comment: No issue here - a couple of Windows 11 machines. Did you update Intel drivers (and perhaps UEFI BIOS as well).

Comment: I checked through Windows Update; it is as updated as can be.

Comment: A comment, but it seems possible the integrated graphics card you mention just isn't great for hardware acceleration.

Comment: FYI: Visual Studio Code isn’t based on Chromium.

Comment: @Anaksunaman hardware acceleration was decent until an unknown time in about January, so it is not a hardware problem. Games still run fine.

Comment: @Ramhound Visual Studio Code bases on Electron Framework which uses Blink as rendering engine and Blink is the layout/browser engine of Chrome(ium). So 1ctinus is not totally wrong...

Comment: The problem is GPU/drivers, not Windows 11. I have the same problem on Intel UHD 620 under Windows 10. But no problem on GeForce 930 (also under 10)